# how to get ttl value of subnet in SL

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to get ttl(Time To Live value) of subnet.

In `SoftLayer_Network_Subnet`, `reverseDomain` property exists so I masking but there was no value:

[image]

```
Subnet.Service service = Subnet.service(api,subnetId);
service.withMask().ipAddresses();
service.withMask().ipAddresses().virtualGuest();
service.withMask().ipAddresses().guestNetworkComponentBinding();
service.withMask().ipAddresses().subnet();
service.withMask().ipAddresses().subnet().endPointIpAddress();
service.withMask().ipAddresses().subnet().endPointIpAddress().ipAddress();
service.withMask().ipAddresses().subnet().endPointIpAddress().virtualGuest();
service.withMask().reverseDomain();
service.withMask().reverseDomain().resourceRecordCount();

Subnet subnet = service.getObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the same problem by using masks ([SoftLayer_Network_Subnet::getObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/getObject)).

But, please try the following: [SoftLayer_Network_Subnet::getReverseDomainRecords](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/getReverseDomainRecords)

This is a Rest example:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/[subnet_id]/getReverseDomainRecords

Method: GET
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: thanks, but i can not matching which is right subnet between resourceRecords and subnet of list

Comment: when a call that api my account was received "Permission denied to getReverseDomainRecords. ", which permissions are need for my account?

Comment: Please, the question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372171/softlayer-api-return-permission-denied-to-getreversedomainrecords