# softlayer API return Permission denied to getReverseDomainRecords

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I was Call getReverseDomainRecords of subnet but ruturn "Permission denied to getReverseDomainRecords. ", which permissions are need for this user for call api?

(com.softlayer.api.ApiException$Internal: Permission denied to getReverseDomainRecords.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following `permission` to the user `"Manage DNS, Reverse DNS and WHOIS"`.

From Portal, please go to: `Users> select the user>Portal Permissions> services`.

To add permissions to a user via API, please review: [Failed to add permission to a SoftLayer user ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798963/failed-to-add-permission-to-a-softlayer-user-id)

In our case the following request helps us to add `"Manage DNS, Reverse DNS and WHOIS"` permission

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[user_id]/addBulkPortalPermission

Method: POST

Json payload:

{
  "parameters": [
    [
      {
        "keyName": "DNS_MANAGE"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, i will check